# SQL TO HQL With Inner Query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql, hql

I'm trying to rewrite my SQL query into HQL friendly format but I'm failing or not getting the expected results.

Any help is appreciated...

```
Select *
FROM
 (
  SELECT distinct on (iNumber)
  equipmentTimestamp,
  name, 
  iNumber, 
  datauserprovidername, 
  latitude, 
  longitude
  FROM 
  positionview
  WHERE outbound = false
  AND referenceIdentifier is null
  AND responseType = 'XYZ'
  AND equipmentTimestamp >='2013-02-09 10:04:14.476'
  AND equipmentTimestamp <='2016-02-12 10:04:14.476'
  order by iNumber desc
) AS derivedInnerQuery
order by equipmentTimestamp desc;
```

I can confirm the query above gets the results I expect but HQL only takes sub queries in the WHERE clause.

In short I want the query to grab the latest position report for each iNumber.

Comment: The outer query is not needed in the first place (not even in plain SQL). But I doubt you can convince your obfuscation layer (=hibernate) to run a statement that contains `distinct on ()`

Comment: I added the outer query so that I can ORDER BY equipmentTimestamp desc rather than ORDER BY iNumber desc

Comment: An `order by inumber, equipmenttimestamp` will achieve the same thing

Comment: `2014-02-18 02:40:00 xyz 1009194 xxx 8.1716666667 98.341
2014-02-18 09:34:00 qaz 1009637 zzz 3.144 100.7346666667
2014-02-17 22:04:00 asd 1009699 xxx 6.2905 99.7865
`

Comment: It orders by iMONumber then timestamp so in reality I do get timestamp ordering only after its been ordered by iMONumber